# Replacing a line with a new one containing a variable

Tags: bash, sed

Here's my code:

```
for num in {0001..1000}; do

   cd ${num}_1000_solar
   sed -i '827s/.*/ if(BigUni==1) fp910=fopen("biguni_${num}.dat","w");/' binary.c
   gcc singl.c binary.c -lm
   cd ..
done
```

sed command writes '{num}' into a file instead of putting there an appropriate value from the loop. How can I replace a line with a string + some variable?

Cheers!

Comment: A much saner approach would be to pass the parameter to `gcc`, like `gcc -DNUM="$num"` and adjust line 827 in the C file to use the defined constant NUM instead.  A much saner approach still, like suggested by @JonathanLeffler, is to pass in this parameter as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `${num}` is to be interpreted by the shell, it must be in double quotes (or outside quotes), not single quotes.

```
for num in {0001..1000}
do
    (
    cd ${num}_1000_solar
    sed -i '827s/.*/ if (BigUni==1) fp910=fopen("biguni_'"${num}"'.dat","w");/' binary.c
    gcc singl.c binary.c -lm
    )
done
```

Having 1000 programs where you change the file name in the source code and recompile (to `a.out` each time) is an abuse of C.  You should pass the file name in as an argument to the program.  In other words, the exercise is only necessary because the setup is deeply flawed.

Also, as a general rule, I avoid `cd subdir` followed later by `cd ..` in scripts when it's feasible.  By running a sub-shell (the `(` and `)` in the revised script), the calling shell process is unaffected by any changes of directory.  Ultimately, it's more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and comment.